# How to only show datalist in the bottom input in HTML

Tags: html, css, select, datalist

I use a select in datalist. But I have an issue. When my datalist show in the top of input, I cannot scroll in my datalist. But it doesn't occur when datalist in the bottom.
Here's my code:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="{{'COMPONENT_PROPERTIES.SEARCH_ICON' | translate}}"
               ng-model="icon.name"
               list="classIcon"
               id="searchIcon"
               ng-change="changeFn(icon.name)">
        <datalist id="classIcon" class="scroll" >
            <select class="selectIcon">
                <option ng-repeat="icon in classService.classesAwesome  "
                        value="{{icon}}"
                        ng-bind-html="icon | highlight: $parent.icon.name ">
                    <i class="{{icon}}"></i> &nbsp;
                    <span ng-bind-html="icon | highlight: $parent.icon.name "></span>
                </option>
            </select>
        </datalist>
```

[image: in the bottom]

[image: in the top]

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code to your CSS.

```
.dropdown1 {
width:290px;
overflow:scroll;
height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was looking for a way to do this and found a simple solution to make it always sit below the input field.

I just customised the actual html element in the CCS like this:

```
datalist { 
  position: absolute;
}
```

I have tested this in Chrome, Mozilla and Edge.

I did find that the issue only really appeared in chrome and it was to do with the list size and screen width dimension as to whether it appeared at the side or above or below.